# How to avoid nginx 400 when PUT empty body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, nginx

I got 400 error when I try to send a PUT request with empty body.
Seems nginx thought it is not an valid request.
Is there any way to change nginx setting or how to set client side to avoid 400 error

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not support chunked requests, so client code must specify correct `Content-Length` header. Nginx returns 411 in the absense of it.

I am not sure why you are getting 400. My advice is to set `error_log` level to `info` at least and see what Nginx complains about.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be because you are trying to correlate CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete) semantics with the HTTP specification REST verbs (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD) with the following incomplete mapping:

1. Create = PUT
2. Retrieve = GET
3. Update = POST
4. Delete = DELETE

However, "PUT" indicates something is to be "put" on the server and when there is an empty body, it is invalid and should always get a 400 response.

- Create = PUT (if, and only if, you are sending the resource
  needed to create the content).
- Create = POST (if you are sending a command to the server to
  create the content using server side resources)
- Retrieve = GET.
- Update = PUT (if, and only if, you are sending the resource
  needed to update the content)
- Update = POST (if you are sending a command to the server to
  update the content using server side resources)
- Delete = DELETE.

Read up on [Post vs PUT](http://www.elharo.com/blog/software-development/web-development/2005/12/08/post-vs-put/)

Comment: Thanks your answer. In Rails world, we use "PUT" for update resource, here why I send PUT request with empty body it because I need change state of the resource by PUT "resource/cancel"